# Hierarchical maven project versions

Tags: maven, version

I have an intricated Maven project with modules and subprojects up to four level of inheritance. Furthermore, some modules depend on modules which are not in the same "subtree" and I am wondering if I can avoid to express the version every time I have module dependency.

For example I have

```
a
 -b
   -c
 -d
   -e
```

Supposing module `e` depends on `c`, what is the best way to specify the version in a DRY manner?

If inside the pom.xml of module `e` I don't specify which version of the `c` module I want, my build will fail. Is there a smart way to handle this versioning problem?

Answer (score 2):

groupId and artifactId denote a single project within maven, but version must be specified (or inherited from a parent pom) in order to determine what version of that project maven needs to reference. It appears redundant , but it is necessary especially if there are many different versions.

Comment: Note that this is important because any change to a dependency, including the version number, means the project itself has changed. If you don't have to change it's version, you end up not being able to rely on all artifacts with a particular version number being the same (excluding SNAPSHOTS).

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to define all artifacts with their appropriate version numbers in a dependencyManagement block in the root of the project like:

```
a (pom.xml)
 -b
   -c
 -d
   -e
```

With the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>project</groupId>
      <artifactId>b</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>project</groupId>
      <artifactId>c</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>project</groupId>
      <artifactId>d</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>project</groupId>
      <artifactId>e</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But with the given structure:

```
a (pom.xml)
 -b
   -c
 -d
   -e
```

a must include a list of modules (packaging pom), b(packaging pom) and d(packaging pom) as well which means a, b and d will never be used as dependencies which means you can omit them from the above block.